# Othello Vs Checkers -- are there any complexity and skill comparisons?

Tags: checkers, othello

Which game is harder to play at a high skill level, Othello or Checkers?  I realize this is a highly subjective question.  I have been playing Othello for 35 years or so, and I'm pretty good Othello player at [FlyOrDie](https://www.flyordie.com/). I recently tried Checkers which I hadn't played for more than 40 years, and I get wiped out pretty bad.  I would guess Othello is conceptually more complicated and Checkers is more about avoiding pitfalls, but I'd like to hear other opinions.

Comment: Othello and Checkers are quite different games; one involves building patterns on the board while the other involves movement on the board.  The required skills aren't very transferable between them, so comparing would be difficult. It would be better to compare Othello to Go, and Checkers to Chess, where skill in one *can* help in the other.

Answer (score 3):

From AI point of view, or at least from a Search-intensive approach, Othello is harder.
Checkers has been weakly solved at 2007. Othello has not been solved yet.

From the paper [Checkers Is Solved](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/231216842_Checkers_Is_Solved):

> Search-intensive approaches to AI will play an
> increasingly important role in the evolution of the field.
> With checkers done, the obvious question is whether
> chess is solvable. Checkers has roughly the square root of the number of positions in chess (somewhere in the 10^40 - 10^50 range). Given the effort required to solve checkers,
> chess will remain unsolved for a long time, barring the
> invention of new technology. The disk-flipping game of
> **Othello is the next popular game that is likely to be solved,
> but it will require considerably more resources than were
> needed to solve checkers**.

Comment: I doubt that chess will ever be solved, now that we have an AI that can reliably win every time ... or rather, that can reliably steamroll the opponent every time.